# bookmarks bar click event listener chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i am working on a **chrome extension** that needs an **event listener** on the **bookmarks bar** buttons so that i could do whatever i want with the bookmark that was clicked  !

i've looked up the [bookmarks api on their site](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html) and the [context menus documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html) trying to reach those bookmarks but i couldn't reach such thing .

Comment: Such a thing does not exist. Have you considered creating a bookmarklet instead?

Comment: Maybe if you could give some more info we could help you find an alternative way of achieving this

Comment: I also need this integration point. What I want it for is to right-click a bookmark folder (e.g. on the bookmark bar) and have a menu item for letting the extension select a random bookmark in that folder.

Answer (score 3):

This is not supported in the Chrome Extensions APIs. [This page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html) gives all of the options available for working with bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome doesn`t have such api to hook the  bookmark bar button,maybe you can implement another add  bookmark bar button after the original bookmark bar button by page action api,